# Android implementation of "onCharacteristicChanged" leaking memory

Tags: android, service, memory-leaks, bluetooth-lowenergy

After observing that my implementation of the BluetoothGattCallback override function "onCharacteristicChanged" is leaking memory I've been trying to understand where the leak is coming from, but without success.  I hope that someone would have advice as to why the memory leak from Log.d inside this function is happening and what could be causing the apparent leak from outside the call.

First off, I must say that I have an android service that implements BLE device interfacing that wakes a closed application when a button press event is received from the device that I'm supporting.   While button presses are a rare occurence, the onCharacteristicChanged function also gets invoked when the device reports battery level and these events occur on a regular cadance.  The memory slowly leaks away and eventually the system re-starts the service after it crashes.

To debug this, I gutted my "onCharacteristicChanged" override implementation and just inserted a memory tracking behavior.  What I noticed is that 192 bytes were leaking due to Log.d calls (the amount scales with the size of the message), plus even more memory is leaking from outside this function.  No other functions in my service are being invoked while I'm watching this in logcat.

Without dumping the entire service, below is the truncated BluetoothGattCallback with the onCharacteristicChanged override function and related support function for acquisition of memory stats that I'm using, plus the logcat output for when the service is just receiving characteristic change events.

After reading source and logcat text, does anyone have advice as to why the memory leak from Log.d inside this function is happening and what could be causing the apparent leak from outside the call?  Any advice as to what may be necessary to quell the memory leak would be greatly appreciated.

**Source**

```
// defined as global to the service
long startingMemUsedSample, endMemUsedSample;

// --------------------------------------------------------------------
// BluetoothGattCallback implementation
// --------------------------------------------------------------------
private final BluetoothGattCallback mGattCallback = new BluetoothGattCallback() {

    // all other overrides truncated from this listing to keep it simple

    @Override
    public void onCharacteristicChanged(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
        startingMemUsedSample = getUsedMemorySize();
        Log.d("onCharacteristicChanged", (startingMemUsedSample - endMemUsedSample) + " bytes leaked out of cycle");

        // the guts of this handler were neutered from this handler for analysis

        endMemUsedSample = getUsedMemorySize();
        Log.d("onCharacteristicChanged", (endMemUsedSample - startingMemUsedSample) + " bytes leaked this cycle");
    }
}

// --------------------------------------------------------------------
// getUsedMemorySize
// --------------------------------------------------------------------
public static long getUsedMemorySize() {
    long freeSize = 0L;
    long totalSize = 0L;
    long usedSize = -1L;
    try {
        Runtime info = Runtime.getRuntime();
        freeSize = info.freeMemory();
        totalSize = info.totalMemory();
        usedSize = totalSize - freeSize;
    } 
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return usedSize;
}
```

**Logcat debug messages received while service is just receiving battery level updates:**

01-21 21:25:01.108 27282-27298/com.acompany.bleservice D/onCharacteristicChanged: 448 bytes leaked this cycle

01-21 21:25:16.069 27282-27299/com.acompany.bleservice D/onCharacteristicChanged: 4448 bytes leaked out of cycle

01-21 21:25:16.069 27282-27299/com.acompany.bleservice D/onCharacteristicChanged: 256 bytes leaked this cycle

01-21 21:25:31.031 27282-27298/com.acompany.bleservice D/onCharacteristicChanged: 4416 bytes leaked out of cycle

01-21 21:25:31.031 27282-27298/com.acompany.bleservice D/onCharacteristicChanged: 192 bytes leaked this cycle

01-21 21:25:45.994 27282-27299/com.acompany.bleservice D/onCharacteristicChanged: 4352 bytes leaked out of cycle

01-21 21:25:45.994 27282-27299/com.acompany.bleservice D/onCharacteristicChanged: 192 bytes leaked this cycle

01-21 21:26:00.956 27282-27298/com.acompany.bleservice D/onCharacteristicChanged: 4224 bytes leaked out of cycle

01-21 21:26:00.956 27282-27298/com.acompany.bleservice D/onCharacteristicChanged: 192 bytes leaked this cycle

01-21 21:26:15.918 27282-27299/com.acompany.bleservice D/onCharacteristicChanged: 4352 bytes leaked out of cycle

01-21 21:26:15.919 27282-27299/com.acompany.bleservice D/onCharacteristicChanged: 192 bytes leaked this cycle

01-21 21:26:30.891 27282-27298/com.acompany.bleservice D/onCharacteristicChanged: 4352 bytes leaked out of cycle

01-21 21:26:30.891 27282-27298/com.acompany.bleservice D/onCharacteristicChanged: 192 bytes leaked this cycle

01-21 21:26:45.844 27282-27299/com.acompany.bleservice D/onCharacteristicChanged: 4352 bytes leaked out of cycle

01-21 21:26:45.844 27282-27299/com.acompany.bleservice D/onCharacteristicChanged: 192 bytes leaked this cycle

01-21 21:27:00.806 27282-27298/com.acompany.bleservice D/onCharacteristicChanged: 4352 bytes leaked out of cycle

01-21 21:27:00.806 27282-27298/com.acompany.bleservice D/onCharacteristicChanged: 192 bytes leaked this cycle

Comment: Noticed one nugget in the description for Log.d: "when you're building the string to pass into Log.d, the compiler uses a StringBuilder and at least three allocations occur: the StringBuilder itself, the buffer, and the String object. Realistically, there is also another buffer allocation and copy, and even more pressure on the gc".  GC's aren't running on this service until available heap is small (started with 1.3MB, then GC around 0.2MB - is this normal for GC?

Comment: By the way, heap size I gave are for running on Android 5.0

Comment: onCharacteristicChanged callbacks can come in different threads, what happens if you log the thread id with 'Process.myTid()', does it change all the time?

Comment: The Pid = 27282, but Tid in the trace above is either 27298 and 27299.  The Tid sometimes toggles from pass-to-pass, and other times it stays one or the other for a couple of passes.

Comment: Not sure if it's leaking memory, but it seems to use memory. I observed a similar thing when concatenating strings in methods, somehow they are kept and eating your memory.

Comment: I've come to the understanding that the Garbage Collector isn't constantly scrubbing, but only appears to do it once my thread has burned through most of its free memory allotment.   So, from this perspective, my question does not appear to be an issue.

Comment: Is there a way for me to mark this item as "not an issue"?